# Sorting a list based on date and time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, sorting, linq

I have a class that is used to basically store samples from data being read from a system. Within that class is a property that I use to store the date and time of that sample:

```
public class ReadingValue
{
    public DateTime DateTimeOfReading { get; set; }
    public float Reading { get; set; }
}
```

I need to sort a list of `ReadingValue` based on the `DateTimeOfReading` property.

This is what I've come up with:

```
public IEnumerable<ReadingValue> Hourly(IList<ReadingValue> readings)
{
    var sortedReadings = readings.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading.TimeOfDay)
        .OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading.Date)
        .OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading.Year);

    return sortedReadings;
}
```

The code seems to work, when I pass in a list of `ReadingValue`'s it returns the list in sorted order. Is there anything I've overlooked or should do differently? I know time and date programming can be a tricky topic with things like timezones, daylight savings etc. but sorting dates and times shouldn't involve any of that, I don't think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should first do `OrderBy` and then you should do `ThenBy` instead of doing another `OrderBy`. What you are currently doing is that you are re-ordering **everything** after your first `OrderBy`.

```
public IEnumerable<ReadingValue> Hourly(IList<ReadingValue> readings)
{
    var sortedReadings = readings.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading.TimeOfDay)
        .ThenBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading.Date)
        .ThenBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading.Year);

    return sortedReadings;
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion really, but I think that in this case of the code it will produce the same results, thanks to the current code first doing order by time of day, then of date, then of year.

Comment: This question seems to be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3047455/1310566 . Using `ThenBy` is the correct way to do that.

Comment: This isn't quite the same as the OP's code, and **will** change the order of the list significantly.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: the current version of LINQ to objects uses a stable sort, but other implementations may not.  So while you are right that in this instance it doesn't make a difference, that is only coincidentally true.  It is not part of the definition for OrderBy, and MS is free to change it at any time, and other C# implementations (Mono for instance) are free to use an unstable sort.

Comment: @jmoreno Agreed. The version with `ThenBy` is definitely better.

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify it like this -

```
public IEnumerable<ReadingValue> Hourly(IEnumerable<ReadingValue> readings)
{
    return readings.OrderBy(x => x.DateTimeOfReading);
}
```

And why is that method called Hourly?  Perhaps OrderReadings would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@PankajGupta](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/78053/pankaj-gupta) answer I would like to add, that you better should use an `IEnumerable<ReadingValue>` instead of an `IList<ReadingValue>` as the methods argument type.

In this way you aren't restricted to pass an `IList<>` but you can for instance pass any array `ReadingValue[]`, `ICollection<ReadingValue>` or any object which implements an `IEnumerable<ReadingValue>`to this method as well.

---

Because methodnames should be made out of verbs or verb phrases you should consider to change the methodname from `Hourly` to `SortHourly()`.

See: [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx)